# Connect local wired network to another network

Tags: networking

I live in an apartment which comes with exactly one ethernet port, and a wifi network I can connect to to access the internet. I would like to create my own separate wired local network with its own DHCP server for my devices, but still have an internet connection through the available ethernet port.

I was wondering if this is possible, and if so, how I can go about doing it.

Thank you!

(For context, I would like to try this because, for some reason neither I nor the ISP support could figure out, devices that connect to the apartment network cannot see each other. Even when they are connected to the same switch which is then connected to the ethernet port. Since I don't have access to their router and can't set up my own separate internet connection, I thought that the best solution is to set up a wired local network, and somehow still get internet access from my apartment.)

Comment: yes, you can implement your own network. just buy a standard home router and plug the Ethernet cable from your apartment into its WAN interface. the devices in different apartments likely cannot see each other because the owner of the switch/router upstream put each port in a separate VLAN, so that each apartment is isolated and you guys can;t hack eachother.

Comment: Yo clarify @FrankThomas post you need an Ethernet router (ie where the wan port is Ethernet). You also need to make sure you LAN subnet is different to the subnet provided to the device plugged into the wall (is the IP given to the WAN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased an ethernet router as suggested by @FrankThomas and @davidgo, and it was exactly the solution I was looking for.

The router is connected through its WAN port to the apartment network, and all my devices are part of its network.